# Up and hamburger icon issue with DrawerFragment and ActionBarDrawerToggle(v7)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, actionbardrawertoggle

I've got an issue with dealing with ActionBarDrawerToggle(v7) and icons.

Basically, i've got a classical Activity with a DrawerFragment and Fragments to be displayed and it works.

My issue occurs when i try to replace a Fragment with another for detail view (List/Detail Fragments).

I push my new DetailFragment with:

```
private void putDetailFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentName) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(fragmentName)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(mTitleId).toUpperCase());
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setHomeAsUp(getSupportActionBar(), true);
    }
}

public void setHomeAsUp(ActionBar actionBar, boolean show) {
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(show);
    setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(!show);
}

public void setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    if (mDrawerToggle != null) {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(enabled);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    if(mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(enabled ? DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED : DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the arrow is not animated as it is with opening the drawer. And when i go back from my DetailFragment, the hamburger icon's gone.

Does anyone has a clue what's wrong here? It was working nice with ActionBarDrawerToggle(v4), but not with the new animated one.

Thanks !

Comment: Try calling `drawerToggle.setIndicatorEnabled()` rather than `setHomeAsUp()`.

Comment: Please add this code in your question.